# Getting Data from HTTP Request Xamarin

Tags: rest, xamarin, xamarin.forms, httprequest

I want to get and pass data from my HTTPWebRequest  to my sync page. I am new to MVVM so I don't know if I am correct but so far I can check if there is a result. I tried to watch a lots of video tutorials and forums still I can't find what I need. I was hoping you guys have a answer for me. I have been struggling with this for a week now.

The flow of my project:
- The user will login when it is correct, The user will be redirected to my sync page where it will get all the users data from my server and insert the data into SQLite Database.

My questions are:
*1. How can I get the data and specific data from my HTTPWebRequest?

2. Is my HTTPWebRequest service correct?

3. Is my MVVM correct? 

4. Is my navigation to my next page is correct?*

My code:

## **LoginPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TBSMobileApplication.Data;
using TBSMobileApplication.ViewModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace TBSMobileApplication.View
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LoginPageViewModel loginModel;
        public LoginPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            BindingContext = new LoginPageViewModel();
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<LoginPageViewModel,string>(this, "Login Alert", (sender,Username) =>
            {
                DisplayAlert("Login Error", "Please fill-up the form", "Ok");
            });

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<LoginPageViewModel, string>(this, "Connected", (sender, Username) =>
            {
                DisplayAlert("Connection Info", "Connected", "Ok");
            });

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<LoginPageViewModel, string>(this, "Not Connected", (sender, Username) =>
            {
                DisplayAlert("Connection Info", "Not Connected", "Ok");
            }); 

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<LoginPageViewModel, string>(this, "Http", (sender, Username) =>
            {
                DisplayAlert("Login Error", "Username or Password is incorrect", "Ok");
            });

            entUsername.Completed += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                entPassword.Focus();
            };
        }

        protected async Task OnAppearingAsync()
        {
            var db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB>();
            var conn = db.GetConnection();

            if (conn != null)
            {
                await conn.CreateTableAsync<UserTable>();
                await conn.CreateTableAsync<RetailerTable>();
                await conn.CreateTableAsync<ContactsTable>();
            }

            base.OnAppearing();
        }
    }
}
```

LoginPageViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using TBSMobileApplication.View;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TBSMobileApplication.ViewModel
{
    public class LoginPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        void OnProperyChanged(string PropertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }

        public string username;
        public string password;

        public string Username
        {
            get { return username; }
            set
            {
                username = value;
                OnProperyChanged(nameof(Username));
            }
        }

        public string Password
        {
            get { return password; }
            set
            {
                password = value;
                OnProperyChanged(nameof(Password));
            }
        }

        public ICommand LoginCommand { get; set; }

        public LoginPageViewModel()
        {
            LoginCommand = new Command(OnLogin);
        }

        public void OnLogin()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
            {
                MessagingCenter.Send(this, "Login Alert", Username);
            }
            else
            {
                var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;

                if (current == NetworkAccess.Internet)
                {
                    var link = "http://192.168.1.25:7777/TBS/test.php?User=" + Username + "&Password=" + Password;
                    var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format(@link));
                    request.ContentType = "application/json";
                    request.Method = "GET";

                    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                    {
                        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            Console.Out.WriteLine("Error fetching data. Server returned status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                            {
                                var content = reader.ReadToEnd();

                                if (content.Equals("[]") || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
                                {
                                    MessagingCenter.Send(this, "Http", Username);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new DatabaseSyncPage(), true);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessagingCenter.Send(this, "Not Connected", Username);
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions in a single post.  It makes them more difficult to reply to.  At a glance your code appears correct - but only you can tell if it is working or not.  Is it?  If it is not, what specifically is wrong with it?  Are you getting an error or exception?  What is it doing (or not doing) differently than you expect?

Comment: @Jason there is no error I just want an expert opinion because I am new to Xamarin. My main question is how can I get an specific data from HTTP Request

Comment: if it's json data, then you use a json parser to parse it and extract the data.  See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: @Jason what part of my code do I put  JsonConvert.SerializeObject?

Comment: You don't.  JSON is already serialized, you want to de-serialize it into an object.  JSON.net has excellent docs and examples, take the time to read them.

Comment: @Jason sorry, I mean deserialize where to I put that? in here? in this part? using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))

Comment: after you've read the response into the content variable

Comment: @Jason so above App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new DatabaseSyncPage(), true);

Comment: You can use https://app.quicktype.io to generate the model that the json can serialize into